# check numpy array values b/w 2 columns of pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, data-science

I have a numpy array of size (352, 5) and also have a pandas DataFrame.

Objective is to check whether first and second columns of the numpy array exist in a range of 2 pandas columns and if yes then get the index of that particular row and then do something

**Example**:-

```
stats = [[      246       1102    1678    2214  172182]
         [      678       1005    1688   2214   3528850]
         [     1031       241     17     23     331]]
```

df:-

```
hpos     hpos_end     vpos     vpos_end
245      298          1100     1124  
672      685          1000     1010
```

Result:-
`stats[0]` is present in the very first row of df since 246 lies b/w 245 and 298 and 1102 lies b/w 1100 and 1124 and same goes for next element of stats. I want to obtain the index of the row it lies in(if it does).

My approach till now:-

```
for x, y, w, h, area in stats[:]:
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if x in range(int(df['HPOS'][row.Index]), int(df['HPOS_END'][row.Index])) and y in range(
                    int(df['VPOS'][row.Index]), int(df['VPOS_END'][row.Index])):
            desired_index = row.Index
```

is there a faster/optimum way to achieve my objective as iterating a df would be the last thing I would like to do

Note: both numpy array and the df are already in sorted in ascending order based on the first two columns for numpy array and ['hpos', 'vpos] for df

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you :)